# Qt wizard back button Ui issue

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, back-button, wizard

I'm new with Qt and I'm making a little application. I've do it with QWizard and QWizardPages.
I Have added 2 CustomButtons to the wizard so it has 5 buttons down: ButA, ButB, Back, Next/Finish, and Cancel.

ButA and ButB don't have to appear in all WizardPages. Eg:
WP0: just ButB
WP1: ButA and ButB

To do that, I have:

```
void WP0::initializePage()
{
   wizard()->button(QWizard::CustomButton1)->setVisible(false);
}
```

With that when the app starts, you can't see butA. BUT if you go to the next page (where you see ButA and ButB) and then you click on BackButton, then you see ButA in WP0.
I supose that then you click on BackButton there is no call to WP0::initializePage() so my question is: how or where should I call  that `wizard()->button(QWizard::CustomButton1)->setVisible(false);`
to never see ButA on WP0 ? Or what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your question completely. your description is kind of complicated. I think you should try button's events.  It means you should call this function in press event or something like that and it's better that you define a boolean variable for true or false and call it by reference. I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, so you mean something like    `connect(this, wizard()->button(QWizard::BackButton)->pressed(), wp0, SLOT(inibutton())`     and then put    `wizard()->button(QWizard::CustomButton1)->setVisible(false);` in that inibutton() ?

Comment: In general yes but I think you don't need to define signal and slot. It should have some defined slots like press event.